# Eclipse+STS or STS all function invalid

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I follow some guide, In the video, Their IDE have all those functions (by default! no config needed):

No auto compile in any type
No Spring entry in "NEW" or "XML Configure File" in XML or anything handy
No Spring XML editor in "OpenWith"
etc....

Almost everything is missing

I try both way: Download STS4 or install STS in Eclipse
None of them working

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

So: How to get those lost function ?

Comment: What is "some guide"? Is it a guide for STS3 or STS4?

Comment: STS4 latest , same thing i do in IDEA all working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is probably using STS3, which contains all the features for Spring XML config files that you mentioned. However, the tooling that you have installed is Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse, which comes with a different set of features. It supports Spring XML config files, too, but in a different way. It is much more focused on implementing apps on top of Spring Boot. You can find more details in the Spring Tools 4 wiki: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki